# Environment is not passed to process opened by proc_open

Tags: php, process, proc-open

I have a problem passing environment variables to processes that i opened with proc_open.
I found the following example on https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php

```
<?php
$descriptorspec = array(
   0 => array("pipe", "r"),  // stdin is a pipe that the child will read from
   1 => array("pipe", "w"),  // stdout is a pipe that the child will write to
   2 => array("file", "/tmp/error-output.txt", "a") // stderr is a file to write to
);

$cwd = '/tmp';
$env = array('some_option' => 'aeiou');

$process = proc_open('php', $descriptorspec, $pipes, $cwd, $env);

if (is_resource($process)) {
    // $pipes now looks like this:
    // 0 => writeable handle connected to child stdin
    // 1 => readable handle connected to child stdout
    // Any error output will be appended to /tmp/error-output.txt

    fwrite($pipes[0], '<?php print_r($_ENV); ?>');
    fclose($pipes[0]);

    echo stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);
    fclose($pipes[1]);

    // It is important that you close any pipes before calling
    // proc_close in order to avoid a deadlock
    $return_value = proc_close($process);

    echo "command returned $return_value\n";
}
?>
```

The example should echo the env array like the documentation say. But on my machine (PHP 5.4.6-1ubuntu1.4 (cli)) the echoed array is empty. Are there some Suhosin or php.ini restrictions that ban env var passing to processes? I have no idea.

Comment: Are you using PHP through an Apache module or via CGI, FastCGI, PHP-FPM... etc ?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.environment.php#98113 - read that, and if your ENV is enabled in INI, then include information in your question that SirDarius asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `$_ENV` is empty, you should have a look at your [`variables_order`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.variables-order) ini setting and ensure that the value contains the `E`

However, you can use `$_SERVER` instead:

```
fwrite($pipes[0], '<?php print_r($_SERVER); ?>');
```

It will contain environment variables too and should be enabled at `99.999%` of servers (I guess)

Comment: The $_SERVER is the only solution that works fine for me :) Like i said in the reply to drull, the 'E' in variables_order only work in combination with allow globals. But that would be the gate to (security) hell

Comment: :) ... if you once find out what caused the problem it would be nice if you could add that information here

Comment: Oh yes you are right. I left my variables_order to "GPCS" but i use $_SYSTEM to retrieve the variables instead of $_ENV. This works fine for me.

Comment: ok, should work fine (unless you are using environment variable names that are already part of `$_SERVER`

Answer (score 1):

Set

```
variables_order = "EGPCS"
```

in your php.ini

Comment: Indeed my variables_order is "GPCS". But adding the E does not work. Because, if i read the doc correctly, you have to set register_globals to on. This is not recommened by serveral sources. http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php